# Get another app's templates in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

This is the structure of my site:

```
mysite
    app_a
       templates
           a.html
    app_b
       templates
           b.html
       views.py
```

In `views.py`, I want to get `a.html`,

So I use this :

```
return render_to_response('app_a/a.html')
```

but it shows an error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**just use render_to_response('a.html')**

Assuming you have the default app directory template loaders on, the problem is that the template path is actually `a.html`

So in your current format, you would write `a.html` not `app_a/a.html`

The recommended format for template directories is

```
mysite
    app_a
       templates
           app_a
               a.html
    app_b
       templates
           app_b
               b.html
       views.py

    global_templates
       app_b
            b.html
```

which would work with your example of `app_a/a.html`

The reason this format is recommended is so you can sanely override templates on a per-app basis.

You can easily get conflicting template names if all files are directly in the app template directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a TEMPLATE_DIRS variable in settings.py, which is a tuple of directories where templates are searched for.  If you add the template directory from both apps to TEMPLATE_DIRS, you should be okay (just watch out for conflicts in the search path).

Comment: For example, my templates/ directory is at the top level (i.e. shared between all apps).  In settings.py, I indicate the templates' location like so: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),)   ... if I wanted to add more template directories to the search path, I would append additional paths after the comma.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings, try adding `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` to the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting as this will make available all the templates for the apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. That way you don't need to put them all under one master directory.

See the [Django Documentation for template loaders](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)